# Is there a straightforward proof that algebraic numbers are dense without reference to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that the simplest proof that the set of algebraic numbers is dense is that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{A}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense.

What I'm wondering is whether there's a proof that $\mathbb{A}$ is dense which is roughly as simple as the proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, but uses only polynomials.

Comment: Well, the simplest polynomials helpful here are degree 1. And the roots of polynomials of degree 1 over $\mathbb{Q}$ are...

Comment: @aschepler Thanks! I was making this far too complicated in my head. All one needs to do is show that first degree polynomials are dense, which is basically the same thing as showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense. No need to worry about polynomials of higher degrees! Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: $\mathbb A\,$ is closed under addition and multiplication, so any rational [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of points in $\,\mathbb A\,$ lies in $\,\mathbb A\,$. Whether you consider that to be "*straightforward*" depends on the background and context, though.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Wouldn't they be? 

$x = \frac{a}{b}$ ->

$x - \frac{a}{b} = 0$ ->

$bx - b\frac{a}{b} = 0b$ ->

$bx - a = 0$

Right?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm sorry. Sloppy language on my part. Yes, I meant that the _roots_ of polynomials are dense.

Answer (score 0):

I think a variation of the Archimedean Principle can work.

For any prime $p$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}$ is algebraic and irrational. There's an infinite number of primes, so $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists$ infinite $p$ so that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}<\epsilon$. Let $x$ be a positive transcendental number. Let B be the set of all positive integer multiples of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}$ less than $x$. These are all aglebraic and irrational if they exist. For some $p$, B is non-empty. By definition of the set, it has to be bounded. By the completeness of the reals, it has an upper bound $s$ and $s<x<s+1/\sqrt{p}$.

$1/\sqrt{p}$ can be made arbitrarily small, so there's an algebraic number within any open neighborhood of a transcendental number. It follows that algebraic numbers are dense.

$\sqrt{p}$ are solutions to $px^2-1=0$. They are defined by second degree polynomials. Only irrational numbers are considered in the construction of $s$.

Comment: Stop me if I'm wrong, but this looks like it could be tweaked into a definition of transcendental numbers as the limit of a sequence of algebraic numbers, similar to Dedekind cuts as a definition of irrational numbers...?

Comment: I believe that is correct after reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut

Comment: @RichJensen A Dedekind cut defines a *real* number, whether rational or irrational, and in the latter case whether algebraic or transcendental. It is not clear why you think you'd need a separate definition for trascendentals alone, and what would be the premises and construction you'd propose for that.